# How can I find the target Java version for a compiled class?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

#### Duplicate:

> [Tool to read and display Java .class versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065/tool-to-read-and-display-java-class-versions)

If I have a compiled Java class, is there a way to tell from just the class file what its target version compatibility is?  Specifically, I have a number of class files, compiled to Java 6, which are running under Java 5 and giving the the "Unrecognized version" error.  I want to be able to look at a class file and find what its target version compatibility is without running the JVM. Any ideas?

Comment: ... and of course, the file utility is also included on MacOS, if you're willing to use the Terminal.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found this on the net and it works.

> Every '.class' file starts off with
>   the following:
>
> - Magic Number [4 bytes]
> - Version Information [4 bytes]
>
> A hexdump of a '.class' file compiled
>   with each of the following options
>   reveals:
>
> `javac -target 1.1` ==> `CA FE BA BE 00 03 00 2D`
>   `javac -target 1.2` ==> `CA FE BA BE 00 00 00 2E`
>   `javac -target 1.3` ==> `CA FE BA BE 00 00 00 2F`
>   `javac -target 1.4` ==> `CA FE BA BE 00 00 00 30`
>
> Perhaps you could use this information
>   to write your own '.class' file
>   version checking utility, using Java,
>   or perhaps a scripting or shell
>   language ;) !
>
> I hope this helps.
>
> Anthony Borla

From: http://bytes.com/groups/java/16603-how-determine-java-bytecode-version

Comment: Great, but what about versions 1.5 and 1.6, which are the ones I care about?

Comment: Seems like the last number represents the final version hex 31 = dec 49 hex 32 = dec 50.  That's what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: Version 1.6 = 32 and 1.5 is 31

Comment: I found the answer [provided here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148) to be slightly more enlightening.

Comment: `javap -verbose MyClass` => Major Version 49 (decimal)= Java 1.5, 50= Java 1.6, 51= Java 1.7, 52= Java 1.8.

Answer (score 45):

You can use the **javap** utility that comes with the standard JDK.

```
javap -verbose MyClass

Compiled from “MyClass.java”
public class MyClass extends java.lang.Object
SourceFile: “MyClass.java”
minor version: 3
major version: 45
```

Comment: while it may be considered "better" it is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Same result can be achieved using file program (on most GNU/unix system) :

    file Foo.class 

Foo.class: compiled Java class data, version 45.3

BTW: how to compile to produce this output (45.3) , is .45 jdk1.x or j2me ?

Comment: There is a table of major version numbers (like major version 51 = Java 1.7 and so on), on the [Wikipedia article for Java class file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout).

Comment: The exact version can be dumped using "javap -version target.class"

Comment: @user2149140 `javap -version` reports the version of `javap`, not your `target.class`

Answer (score 5):

Linux/Unix users have a nice tool out of the standard toolbox: [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) utility. Modern versions can detect the Java class fersion version and even output Java version for known class file types.

Example output:

```
com/sample/Tracker.class: compiled Java class data, version 45.3
com/sample/TestListener.class: compiled Java class data, version 49.0 (Java 1.5)
```

And it fits very nicely into the standard Unix scripting toolchain.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from: http://twit88.com/blog/2008/09/22/java-check-class-version/

```
try {
    String filename = "C:\\MyClass.class";
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    int magic = in.readInt();
    if (magic != 0xcafebabe) {
        log.info(filename + " is not a valid class!");
    }
    int minor = in.readUnsignedShort();
    int major = in.readUnsignedShort();
    log.info(filename + ": " + major + " . " + minor);
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.info("Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the byte offset 6 and 7 in the file (in a hex dump probably), which tells you which version is used. I think the [Bytecode Visualizer](http://www.drgarbage.com/bytecode-visualizer-lt.html) (eclipse plugin) can see which version a class file is made for.

[Further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(file_format))