# "Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins

Tags: android, eclipse, certificate

I am using Eclipse Android plugins to build a project, but I am
getting this error in the console window:

```
[2010-02-03 10:31:14 - androidVNC]Error generating final archive:
Debug certificate expired on 1/30/10 2:35 PM!
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can someone tell why does this happen?

Comment: Does your system date changed, cause its of 25 year valid certificate(as recommended while signing application). its not event more than 5 year old specifically

Comment: You need to create new keystore

Answer (score 2272, accepted):

Delete your debug certificate under `~/.android/debug.keystore` on **Linux and Mac OS X**; the directory is something like `%USERPROFILE%/.android`on **Windows**.

The Eclipse plugin should then generate a new certificate when you next try to build a debug package. You may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate.

Comment: On Windows I had to delete the debug.keystore and make some changes to get a new compile going. I created a new test project, and the new debug.keystore was generated.

Comment: It will also be re-generated for the current project if you 'clean' the project (go to Project -> Clean...)

Comment: There is now a bug tracker issue requesting this to be fixed. Please vote for it. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15370

Comment: Clean did not fix the problem for me, I needed to rm ~/.android/debug.keystore by hand.

Comment: @James Deleting the keystore by hand is the first part of the answer above. Cleaning the project (or rebuilding) is what you need to do to generate a new keystore.

Comment: I don't like the idea of using 'clean', because the last time I did that, it deleted my R.java file and caused more problems. Just make some change to the code and save. That should force a rebuild.

Comment: The directory location on Windows 7 is: C:\Users\[Username]\.android

Comment: @Manfred Moser - https://review.source.android.com/#/c/22128/ looks like the fix is in.  Default will be a 30 year certificate.

Comment: On Vista and win7 this is here: %USERPROFILE%\.android

Comment: worked for me on mac/eclipse. You need to perform a clean before the error will be gone. No code modification needed then.

Comment: yeah but you lose app data in either solutions of deleting the debug signature.. is there anyway of saving it?

Comment: If you have root access to the device, you can just copy the important contents of the /data/data/<package.name> directory.

Comment: IMPORTANT: sravan below is correct that Mac hides files and folders that begin with a dot, just like Windows. To modify your settings so that you can see and delete the file in that hidden folder, follow the instructions here: http://guides.macrumors.com/Viewing_hidden_files_on_a_Mac

Comment: Found this same issue with a build server running Team City and ant. The keystore was located at C:\.android\  Took me a while to find.

Comment: For me (on Windows 7), it was enough to remove the file 'debug.keystore' from '%USERPROFILE%/.android' and then restart eclipse.

Comment: @SSZero When that happens, closing the project in the package explorer and opening it again usually does the trick for me.

Comment: Clean did not fix the problem for me, had to delete ~/.android folder manually

Comment: Two years on, still working like a charm. Wish they'd fix this issue, or at least inform it when it occurs

Comment: I formatted my pc and i lost my old debug.keystore.
But now i want that same keystore.
Any way to get the older debug.keystore ?

Comment: I had to restart Eclipse as well... (on Linux)

Comment: Is there a way to extend the certificate date without delete

Comment: I came looking here after doing a console build and getting this error; in Eclipse I got only a popup that said, "There was an error(s) building this project, please fix the error and try again." but with no indication what the error was in any window that I could find. (I'm an Eclipse noob.)

Comment: debug.keystore is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\.android in my case. But now it works !

Comment: If you are shifting from Eclipse to android studio see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode/27639043#27639043

Comment: How can we detect which os in build.gradle file?

Answer (score 341):

Upon installation, the Android SDK generates a `debug` signing certificate for you in a keystore called `debug.keystore`. The Eclipse plug-in uses this certificate to sign each application build that is generated.

Unfortunately a debug certificate is only valid for 365 days. To generate a new one you must delete the existing `debug.keystore` file. Its location is platform dependent - you can find it in **Preferences - Android - Build - Default debug keystore**.

Comment: A change to make the default 30 years was accepted on 6 Apr 2011: https://review.source.android.com/#change,22128

Comment: If you delete your debug.keystore, how would you update your application?

Comment: @user739375, the debug.keystore is only used for debugging, a separate certificate is used for "production".

Comment: @JamesMoore I really astonished that how old the certificate was

Answer (score 265):

It's a pain to have to delete all your development .apk files, because the new certificate doesn't match so you can't upgrade them in all your AVDs. You have to get another development MAP-API key as well. There's another solution.

You can create your own debug certificate in `debug.keystore` with whatever expiration you want. Do this in the `.android` folder under your `HOME` directory:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000
```

`keytool.exe` can be found in the JDK bin folder (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\` on Windows).

ADT sets the first and last name on the certificate as "Android Debug", the organizational unit as "Android" and the two-letter country code as "US". You can leave the organization, city, and state values as "Unknown". This example uses a validity of 14000 days. You can use whatever value you like.

Comment: I like this because it provides a more long-term fix until the SDK provides a better way to handle the expiring cert.

Comment: I like this because I don't need to use eclipse at all.

Comment: I'm assuming that this is to be typed under the command line. If so, I get a "keytool is not recognized" error. Can you further explain this method?

Comment: keytool can be found in your JDK's bin directory (any OS). I usually add this bin directory to my PATH so the above would work from anywhere. You could either find your JDK bin directory and add it to your PATH, or you could put the full pathname to keytool on the command line.

Comment: As other commenters have pointed out, Google seems to have extended the default duration of the debug certificate so deleting the debug.keystore file and doing clean/build is much easier.

Comment: I'm doing a CI build using hudson, and this works where the eclipse answer doesn't.

Answer (score 82):

On Vista, this worked:

1. DOS: `del c:\user\dad\.android\debug.keystore`
2. ECLIPSE: In Project, Clean the project. Close Eclipse. Re-open Eclipse.
3. ECLIPSE: Start the Emulator. Remove the Application from the emulator.

You are good to go.

I was pretty worried when I say that error, but I fixed it from reading here and playing around for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 70):

- **WINDOWS**

**Delete: debug.keystore**
located in
**`C:\Documents and Settings\\[user]\.android`**, Clean and build your project.

- **Windows 7**
  go to **`C:\Users\[username]\.android`** and delete debug.keystore file.

Clean and build your project.

- **MAC**

Delete your keystore located in **`~/.android/debug.keystore`** Clean and build your project.

In all the options if you can´t get the new debug.keystore just restart eclipse.

Answer (score 58):

In Windows 7 it is at the path

```
C:\Users\[username]\.android
```

- goto this path and remove `debug.keystore`
- clean and build your project.

Answer (score 42):

If a certificate expires in the middle of project debugging, you must do a **manual uninstall**:

Please execute 
`adb uninstall <package_name>` in a shell.

Answer (score 40):

On a Mac, open the Terminal (current user's directory should open), cd ".android" ("ls" to validate debug.keystore is there). Finally "rm debug.keystore" to remove the file.

Answer (score 37):

The Android SDK generates a "debug" signing certificate for you in a keystore called `debug.keystore`.The Eclipse plug-in uses this certificate to sign each application build that is generated.

Unfortunately a debug certificate is only valid for 365 days. To generate a new one, you must delete the existing `debug.keystore` file. Its location is platform dependent - you can find it in *Preferences* -> *Android* -> *Build* -> *Default debug keystore.

### If you are using Windows, follow the steps below.

DOS: del c:\user\dad.android\debug.keystore

Eclipse: In Project, Clean the project. Close Eclipse. Re-open Eclipse.

Eclipse: Start the Emulator. Remove the Application from the emulator.

### If you are using Linux or Mac, follow the steps below.

Manually delete `debug.keystore` from the `.android` folder.

You can find the `.android` folder like this: `home/username/.android`

Note: the default `.android` file will be hidden.

So click on the places menu. Under select home folder. Under click on view, under click show hidden files and then the `.android` folder will be visible.

Delete `debug.keystore` from the `.android folder`.

Then clean your project. Now Android will generate a new `.android folder` file.

Answer (score 35):

I had this problem couple of weeks ago. I first tried the [troubleshooting](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/troubleshooting.html#signingcalendar) on the Android developer site, but without luck. After that I reinstalled the Android SDK, which solved my problem.

Answer (score 34):

H-m-m-m. Interesting how so many people have had slightly different experiences with this. I remember the days when this was considered a sign that the software was not ready for release, and the team would actually fix it BEFORE users started seeing these problems:(

My own experience was just a little different. I had already tried Project>Clean, but still got the same build failure. Then I deleted the debug.keystore (under .android) just as the first answer said. Still got the same problem. Then I did a clean again, and wonder of wonders, it worked!

Now don't get me wrong, I am glad that I got it working thanks to the hints in this thread. But clearly clean isn't working right, and how did it find an expired key after I deleted the keystore??? Clearly something is wrong with Eclipse or the ADT -- not so sure which.

Comment: Eclipse tends to cache files, so a clean/refresh is required sometimes to let it know that the file has changed on disk.

Answer (score 34):

On Ubuntu, this worked:

I went to `home/username/.android` and I renamed `keystore.debug` to `keystoreold.debug`. I then closed Eclipse, started Eclipse, and SDK created new certificate `keystore.debug` in that folder.

You then have to uninstall/reinstall apps you installed via USB Debugging or an unsigned APK ("unsigned" APK = signed with debug certificate).

Answer (score 15):

For windows xp go to `C:\Documents and Settings\%userprofile%\.android` and delete **debug.keystore** file, restart the eclipse  and now your project get build without error.

Example path:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\raja.ap\.android\
```

[read-here-for-more](http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/keytool/).

Answer (score 15):

**First close the eclipse then**

Open CMD by Window **Key + R** or via **Run as Admin**

Follows the following step

```
del "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore"
keytool -genkey -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 30000
```

after this restart eclipse.

Answer (score 14):

In Windows `debug.keystore` file is localtes at `C:\Users\%Username%\.android` folder. This file is created when you install your android SDK and is valid only for a year. After this perod you will start getting this error `Error getting final archive: Debug certificate expired on xx/xx/xxxx`.

To remove this error simply delete the file and run the program again. In my Eclipse I have enabled `Project->Build Automatically` so it directly worked but in case you have disabled it you will need to clean the project `Project->Clean`.. select your project and press ok. Then you will need to build it manually. 3rd click on your project and select `Build project`.(Note - You will only see this option if you have diabled Build Automatically feature in your Projects Menu)

Answer (score 8):

After you install the `Android SDK in Eclipse`, it generates a debug signing certificate for you in a *keystore* called **debug.keystore**. The Eclipse plug-in uses this certificate to sign each application build that is generated.

Now, the problem with this debug certificate is that it is only valid for a year, or 365 days. `If your Eclipse IDE uses an expired debug certificate, you will not be able to create and/or deploy an Android app`.

To fix this problem all you need to do is delete the **debug.keystore** file.

1. **`Go to Preferences`**
2. **`Android`**
3. **`Build`**
4. **`Default debug keystore`**

There you should see the folder where the file is located. Simply delete that file and you are good to go.

For more info. you can visit

> http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 2):

To fix this problem, simply delete the debug.keystore file.

The default storage location for AVDs is

> In ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux.
>
> In C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP
>
> In C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Also see this link, which can be helpful.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

Delete the debug.keystore located at `C:\Users\%Username%\.android` folder. Then run the app. It will generate the new one.