# Android Launch - Inexplicable error

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application, I was doing just fine then I made some changes to the code.
Everything went fine, no error messages, until I ran the code. Then I get this in a popup dialog:

> Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application

The title of the popup dialog is `Android Launch`. 
I know this isn't much to go on, but this is all I am getting. I get nothing in the console at the bottom of Eclipse either.

The dialog message has no Details button. =/

Comment: Assuming this is Eclipse, there should be a Details button on that dialog, plus syntax error highlights in the source editors and on the icons in the project tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may mean that you have an error in one of the project's XML files. When an XML file is malformed (missing tags, incorrect values, etc.), Eclipse is able to sense that the project can't compile correctly, but it can't tell where the problem is. Have you added or changed any XML files since the last successful run, such as a layout resource or the manifest? If so, I'd suggest going back and checking your changes to make sure they're correct.

Comment: It's probably related to a new .XML file, but when I go back and delete the file that I just created, the problem is still there. Then I start a new project and it works just fine again until the same error comes again. I am desperate!

Comment: I've run into this too. Make sure you're not telling the project to build and run while you are on an XML file. Doing so will cause the build to fail and create an error which doesn't actually exist, and so shows up on the project but not on any actual file. You can fix this by rebuilding the project from scratch. In Eclipse this is done by going to Project->Clean...

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/744086c8778093c8?pli=1).

In Eclipse, choose `Window > Show View > Problems` then launch your app.

Check out the Error(s) that occur.

e.g. you might have an [expired debug certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

Find the path to the debug keystore by choosing

```
Window > Preferences > Android > Build
```

Delete your `debug.keystore` file to get going again.

Comment: `Window > Show View > Problems` it's a must while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the left tree of your project and look for the file with the red error icon. In that file on the line of the error there should be another red icon showing an error. If you high light over the icon it should tell you the actual error.

Comment: That is the problem. There are no files with the red icon. Only the project has the red icon.