# Failed to load properties file for android project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I finally was able to build and debug the android platform with [this tutorial](http://source.android.com/source/download.html). I imported my project in eclipse, and afterwards installed [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing). Then I converted my imported project to android project (`Android Tools -> Convert To Android Project`). And now I'm having `Failed to load properties file for project 'droid-platform'` error. Session data:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20100211-1343
java.version=1.5.0_18
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=ru_UA
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86
```

Does anyone know, how do I deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADT does not work good with the platform itself. Actually, the platform is not an android project itself.

Answer (score 3):

Use the contextual menu on the Project in error, "Android Tools"-->"Fix project properties", I also tried "Refresh (F5)" in the same pass, than it worked again.

Answer (score 2):

I really struggled with this one and finally solved it using the solution here:
["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

I also had the error message you mention, but somehow, deleting the keystore fixed everything.

p.s. do a clean after deleting the keystore.

Yusuf

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is to setup some System Environment Variables.

1. Right click on "My Computer" and select "Properties"
2. Select the "Advanced" tab
3. Click the "Environment Variables" button
4. Under "System Variables" find "Path", select is and then click "edit"
5. Scroll to the far right, now you need to add two paths, "C:\Documents and Settings\YOUR_USER_NAME\.android\avd" and "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin", you need to add a ; at the end of each path. Click "Ok" when done.
6. Select the "New" button, for variable name enter "ANDROID_SDK_HOME", and for variable value enter your SDK install path (Default is "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk") and then click "Ok"
7. Restart Eclipse and it should work!

Answer (score 1):

on my mac, with Eclipse and the Android AVD exited,

1) i deleted all projects in my workspace (backup first!),

2) recreated it with the same workspace name and

3) finally restarted eclipse and a new project setup works fine without the "Failed to load properties.." msg.

Answer (score 1):

So easy just choose the project that has an error, and then go to menu>project>build Project

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new file called project.properties in the root of your project.

Add the line:

```
target=android-10
```

Or modify it to whatever version of the Android you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I got the a similar error When following the [Notepad tutorial on the Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html), the first step in Exercise 1 is to create the first project by going to

File->New->Android Project-> "Create project from existing source"

The problem is that when you select the Notepadv1 path to create the project from existing source, Eclipse will take the project out of the parent folder and move it up a level.  For example, if you select

C:\workspace\NotepadCodeLab\Notepadv1

... as the existing source, Eclipse will copy all the contents of that subfolder *except* the AndroidManifest.xml (and Android.mk file) into a new folder one level up, eg.

C:\workspace\Notepadv1

So one workaround is to create the project, close Eclipse, then copy in all the missing files from the old subfolder to the new folder, then open Eclipse again and refresh the folder.

Presto, no more missing files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just add to import the `R.java` (ex:`import com.exercise.teste.R;`) to my class files by right clicking on ex: `R.id.mybutton` and choose import ex; `your.package.name.R`, then `CLEAN`, `BUILD`.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the problem for me was going into eclipse sdk manager and installing the tools there even though I had them installed on my sdk manager. It seems that there 2 separate sdk managers with different files, so try directly going into the sdk manager in Eclipse and seeing if you have the tools installed there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and without installing AUSKey only corrected the error by removing the log4j.jar / Library / Java / Ext on Windows (\C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext) was fixed. In my case, the solution was like this:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=54452

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I manually tried editing the manifest file, "AndroidManifest.xml".  When I made changes using the little GUI provided for editing the file, it works fine.

Make changes via the Manifest General Attributes and Manifest Extras sections that opens up when you double click the "AndroidManifest.xml" file.  Yet beware of changes made directly to the xml, even if they are identical!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but I finally got the solution:

1. Right-click on your Eclipse project.
2. Go to Build Path->Configure Build Path->select Android from left side.
3. In Library section select and remove the existing v7 library
4. Add it again from your imported v7 project.