# Creating Android project fails in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm very new to Android development and while I tried to walk through the most basic [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) using the ADT Bundle I ran into a problem. When following the steps to create a project everything seems fine up to the the final page of the wizard:

[image]

When I click finish the project appears in the package explorer but the wizard doesn't close. When clicking the following errors show up in the error log:

[image]
(There are no StackTraces for the "load properties file" errors; I could provide the others if needed)

Now to the generated Project. This is empty except for a `proguard-project.txt`.

[image]

Here are the things I already tried but no success so far:

- Reinstall SDK
- Download a new ADT Bundle
- Reinstall JDK
- Reboot computer
- Installing the ADT plugin to a normal version of eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was already asked; you can find some things you haven't yet tried here:

[Failed to load properties file for android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288058/failed-to-load-properties-file-for-android-project)

Comment: Thanks, despite my googling I didn't find this question. Adding "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\avd" to the path variable did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Some things you can try:

- Right click project  -> Android Tools -> Fix project properties
- Check if you set the ANDROID_SDK_HOME System Environment Variable.
- Delete your entire workspace (backup first) and recreate it with the    same name.
- Delete the debug.keystore file under %USERPROFILE%/.android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

-Delete your workspace folder let eclips to create new one

-delete your .android folder on C:\Users\"yourusername"

This work for me.