# Failed to run my first android application (see the screenshots)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

Please go through the following and show me the path how should I correct it.

Downloaded Android SDK toolkit, installed Eclipse, followed instruction given over[here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html):
created my first project, followed instruction given over here to run on my device from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html):

and when clicked on run, selected run as android application, selected my android device named as emulator-5554 but then nothing happened after I clicked OK.

Here is the error log:

[image: Error Log]

It is also showing errors for other projects because i deleted their folders from workspace, so ignore them. My current project is MyFirstApp3

Here is log-cat: (This is increasing every second)
[image]

Since as of now the tutorial have not told me to alter the code still here is the code:

```
Package com.example.myfirstapp3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: try to clean a project and rerun emulator (wait on it). Did emulator is in range of SDK you set in manifest?

Comment: Actually found the problem. Its due to bluestack installed on my PC. The android device it was showing while running was Bluestack not my phone. Thats why all those apps are installed on blue stack.
Now why my phone is not showing UP? WIll i have to uninstall bluestack?

Comment: That's a driver problem then, depends on your system/OS and this isn't really the place for such a problem. I would still very much recommend you drop Eclipse rather sooner than later. Look at my answer. Google itself is moving away from it, and both IDEs are very stable.

Comment: Can you run your emulator from SDK manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the new [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) or [IntelliJ Idea Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/),  I wouldn't recommend Eclipse anymore.

(If you don't want to, try cleaning the entire project)

Comment: I have downloaded Eclipse just because I can find step by step tutorial for it on developer.android.com, as am still a noob i need some very finely written tuts. So can you guide me to tutorial for any of these you mentioned?

Comment: Have a look here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-android-studio/ or here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=to8hSys0AHw Other than that, just google for it for numerous other sites. Once the setup is complete, you can still use other tutorials, the coding for Android doesn't change much, it's just a different IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project and/or restarting eclipse. It is acting weird sometimes...

Comment: And this is actually 3rd 4th time i am creating a new project, everytime after restarting, so that won't help.

Comment: You can clean it when you go to Project > Clean Project

Comment: Did the clean. But still no luck.

Comment: You could also try to click on "Android Tools"-->"Fix project properties" in the context menu of your project (I got that answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288058/failed-to-load-properties-file-for-android-project)