# Error: Unable to open class file R.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

Did a fresh install of Eclipse, JDK and android-sdk.

I am currently receiving this error when creating a new project

> [2010-09-26 16:07:56 - Test] ERROR: Unable to open class file C:\workspace\Test\gen\com\example\test\R.java: No such file or directory

What's the reason for this and how do I fix it?

```
Eclipse Helios 32 bit
java version "1.6.0_21"
Android sdk API 8
```

P.S. I'm new to Android development.

EDIT: I tried most of your solutions, but nothing worked. So I started using my friend's install of Eclipse Ganymede.

Comment: if there is an error in one of your resource files the R file doesn't generate. Always something to look for.

Comment: It's probably just the refresh behavior of Eclipse.  After it has been built, just right click on the project and select Refresh (F5).

Comment: i agree with @schwiz even i had the same above problem and tried many answers bellow. nothing worked for me. as i had a error in the xml format in one of the files i didnt knwo where so deleted the project and imported again then it showed only one error. thats the format error. when i fixed it and clean my project all worked well.

Here is my conclusion:
i think if you have error in xml file then answers bellow may not work. 
if you do not have any xml error, then the answers bellow may work for you.

Comment: There was an error in one of my XML files. oooh my God it wasted too much of my time to look for error manually in near about 50xml files. This is really bad on part of eclipse that it doesn't mention real reason for error :(

Comment: right click on Eclipse Icon and if you are using Windows 7 then select run as Administrator. Then go to Project and Select Clean. it Will solve the Problem.

Answer (score 16):

I have had same issue, all what I needed to do, was create project and restart eclipse.

//Edit: Complete collapsing of "Package" tree works as well.

Comment: I think that's the same thing I discovered,  I like your way better :-)

Answer (score 14):

This is a mighty annoying error.

It happens 100% of the time when I create a new android project.

What seems to work for me is to just delete the file (which DOES exist and is accessible by my user), then hit build, and it will regenerate it and stop moaning.

It's clearly a bug as there are too many people getting it simply by filling in the boxes in the new project dialog (like me) without even modifying any code!

Comment: Confirmed that deleting R.java and letting it regenerate works.  Thanks Sam Bartle.

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at your console. It is an **aapt aborted** error. Since aapt is the tool that auto-generates R.java, therefore, R.java was not getting generated.

Since R.java is a auto-generated file that stores information about your drawables you should rebuild your project. Before that have a look at your layout xml files and check them for errors.

Notice that Project -> Build All should be selected. Also try to run your project.

Answer (score 5):

Removing Read Only attribute on Eclipse workspace directory and Project->Clean->Build Project 
did the trick for me. I then clicked on the project directory from within Eclipse and did a F5 (Refresh) . R.java was generated in the gen folder.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error on the creation of new projects myself. After messing around I tried moving the R.Java file into the same location as my projects java file (the src file).  Eclipse then saw I removed the R.Java file from its location and created another and that seemed to clean up the error.....I dont know if it was because eclipse rebuilt the file and then saw it or what but that seemed to work for now.

Comment: this worked for me **once**. then I did a clean&build and I got the same error again.

Comment: i did this is and now eclipse says  
Unknown error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: But maybe this is an error caused by sg else, so for me your solution seems to have worked

Comment: I found out what the problem was.....my debugging key had expired and all I had to do was erase it and eclipse or the adt generated a new one when I went back and cleaned all the projects. It was in the .android file on my computer. It may be in a different spot for you than it was for me

Answer (score 3):

After creating the Project, Right click the Project Folder within the Project Explorer on the Left Tab of Eclipse.

Click on Source->Format.

The Console will say:

[2010-11-24 11:57:42 - YourProject] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

Then you're good to go. Try running your Project and it will compile.

Answer (score 3):

Check your imports. If this has sneaked in, then delete it.

```
import android.R;
```

Answer (score 2):

Had a almost identical issue with Eclipse Helios 64 bit on Linux,  but I had the "1.6.0" API selected like you.  The bizarre thing was I could type;

```
cat <the path it was moaning about>
```

in a console it would display correctly.

I created a new AVD which used Android 2.1, the issue magically vanished. Perhaps it's a bug in Android SDK or Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project name in package explorer. Then click 'Validate'. It will be fine.

Comment: +1 have not seen this solution.  i have got other things to work as well, but this seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to fix it:
Go to your "workspace" folder and make sure it's not "read-only"

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Menu > Projects > clean

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.I was able to solve it by doing the following:

1. go to Window/Preferences/Java/Build Path
2. select 'Folders' and change the output folder to 'gen' (this is where Android looks for the generated java files,but the default in eclipse is 'bin').
3. restart Eclipse

Windows 7,Eclipse 3.5.2

Answer (score 2):

Configure buildpath.. check android , it worked, of course i followed one of the posts mentioned above window, preferences, java, java build path and selected project, 
then created a project, and tried to build same error, then i checked build path and saw android is unchecked, checked it and build again, it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem with no helpful errors.  finally, I tried deleting my debug keystore and it worked:

```
rm ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

I had seen people mention that, but I figured it wasn't my problem because I wasn't getting any errors relating to the debug keystore.  I found the answer here:

["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins/2196397#2196397)

apparently the debug keystore is only valid for one year.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that once you have created your project and you've mention the R.class error --> just restart the Eclipse IDE and everything will be fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

1.-Open Eclipse
2.-Open Window/Preference
3.-Expand JAVA option
4.-Select Build Path
5.-Check the option "Projec"t and uncheck "folder" options
6.-Click on OK
7.-Restart eclipse IDE

Let's go to code !!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by merely cleaning and rebuilding the project. How ever there is a link to the latest version of Eclipse for Android.
**Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Build id: 20100218-1602

(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2005, 2009.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://www.eclipse.org/webtools**

Here is a link to Android Tutorial with Eclipse
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 0):

In mac,
I select Project>Clean
after that, i unchecked Build Automatically
then i run the project and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 64bit, run eclipse as administrator, solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no gen folder after pressing clear...

To solve it, i created a new gen file, then when to Build Path => Configure Path, and pressed ok.

All went smooth after that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following steps are done as solutions:

1. Collapse the project tree structure

2. Go to the workspace and remove the readonly permission of the workspace.

3. right click "default.properties" and go to properties and uncheck the readonly permission in eclipse.( this is done when the workspace shows build error even though there are no compilation issues)