# Android Launch Error in all Android Projects

Tags: android, eclipse

I got stuck in the problem in which I can't able to launch any projects of my workspace related to android. Here the screen shot of error.I have tried all the stuff related cleaning projects and then re-building it.Also my projects doesn't contains any error.Please help me out if someone faced such type of error. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: what does the error log and problems console say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great example for a totally useless error message. If all android projects are affected, it's most likely a problem with the android plugin and not with the projects themselves. You could try removing and reinstalling the plugins.

I probably wouldn't waste time with this and just download a new copy of eclipse.

---

A solution in this very similar question was to create a new workspace and import the projects there: [Eclipse says my Android project(s) contain(s) errors, but there aren't any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408405/eclipse-says-my-android-projects-contains-errors-but-there-arent-any)

The answer there suggests to check `Window -> Show View -> Problems` for some indication why this error is happening.

In [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7a6806e8fb57f74c) updating the android sdk apparently worked.

Comment: Hi @kapep.I also thought same as you but this is second time I have added android plugin to fresh copy of eclipse.Now can you please speak out the solution of this worthless error ?

Comment: @Shashank_Itmaster I've added some more possible solutions. Don't know if they will work but still worth a try. Hopefully you can find a bit more useful error messages in the problem log.

Comment: Hi @kapep, your `Window->Show View->Problems` worked for me.It has shown errors in debug certificate expired.