# Problem with run my first android program

Tags: android

I'm new for android. I try to write HelloAnroid but when I run the program, there are two errors.

```
1. Unable to open class file C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\HelloAndroid\gen\com\example\helloandroid\R.java: No such file or directory
2. Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 22/11/2497, 2:29 น.
```

I don't know why it happens. please help me with these errors.

Comment: That second error happened to me too.  You have to go into where Eclipse stores the Debug certificate and delete it. When you try to build again, Eclipse should generate a new, valid certificate.

Answer (score 2):

You might see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796490/error-unable-to-open-class-file-r-java) and as for "Error generating ..." see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins).

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the build and make sure your SDK is setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

right click the project . go to properties.select java build path.click on the android sdk version.