# com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Debug Certificate expired error

Tags: android, ant

I'm running mac osx. I downloaded the latest version of the SDK starter package (platform api7, revision 2). I use processing version of the build (190).When I try to run I get the errors below.I don't know what is it ?
I hope who can help me getting started with android processing,please.
Thanks.

---

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/ed_crub/Documents/Android SDK/tools/ant/ant_rules_r3.xml:395: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/ed_crub/Documents/Android SDK/tools/ant/ant_rules_r3.xml:209: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Debug Certificate expired on 28/9/2497, 9:17 น.

Total time: 17 seconds
/Users/ed_crub/Documents/Android SDK/tools/ant/ant_rules_r3.xml:395: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/ed_crub/Documents/Android SDK/tools/ant/ant_rules_r3.xml:209: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Debug Certificate expired on 28/9/2497, 9:17 น.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:541)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:394)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
    at processing.app.tools.android.Build.antBuild(Unknown Source)
    at processing.app.tools.android.AndroidMode.runSketchOnDevice(Unknown Source)
    at processing.app.tools.android.AndroidMode.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at processing.app.tools.android.AndroidMode$RunHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Comment: > The following error occurred while executing this line: > com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: > Debug Certificate expired on 28/9/2497, 9:17 The key is to read the error message ;) I don't know why it has such a weird timestamp, but see try this for a solution: ["Debug certificate expired" error in eclipse android plugins][1] [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins/2196397#2196397

Answer (score 36):

When the debug certificate is expired, just `rm ~/.android/debug.keystore`.  Another will be created when it's needed.

The unusual date makes me wonder: what is your TZ set to?  There is a [known bug](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/troubleshooting.html#signingcalendar) if your computer is not using a Gregorian calendar, which can cause the generation of an already expired debug certificate.