# Showing Error !!! Android

Tags: android

When i try to compile and build the application, a red mark is appearing on my application,but there is no error description ..
what will be the reason?

Comment: OMG. Are you empowered by `Eclipse`, the IDE? move the mouse over the `red mark` and GOD may bless you with a holly yellow tooltip.

Comment: Please Refer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins/2196397#2196397

Answer (score 2):

There is always a reason, just need to find it :) Try refreshing and/or cleaning your project. To find error description (in Eclipse) open Problems perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Is probably a weird eclipse/android sdk error. Run Project Cleanup and it should go away.