# Error in newly created android project

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i created project before i could see the .java file on project file a cross mark is displayed and it is showing errors.
Once I executed 'hello world' it ran successfully.

Comment: bocz the project is not build that time once you run it is build and run successfully

Comment: it is not running, it is giving a message that Ur project has errors plz fix then and run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the "Problems" tab, normally at the bottom of your Eclipse workspace. This will tell you what the problem is. Sometimes you just need to do Project > Clean and rebuild it.

Comment: On eclipse console tab it is not displaying anything. Just an alert box is displayed saying that "Your project contains errors, fix them and before running"

Comment: Sure, but that's the CONSOLE tab. Look at the PROBLEMS tab. If it's not there, enable it with Window > Show View > Problems

Comment: When I run, It is showing "Error generating final archive:Debug certificate expired"

Comment: That problem is solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins

Comment: ya i got thank U its running ....which is the best way to develop android app? Is it in JAVA or XML?

Comment: That's a separate question, so really belongs on another topic, but most people suggest using XML as much as possible. Since I answered your original question, please mark it as answered. Thanks!