# R.java could not be opened/ doesnt exist

Tags: android

i've had errors in my project so i saved my files on desktop then deleted the project. i remade the project and pasted my source file back in. it's saying R.java doesn't exist when it does.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This file, R.java, is dynamically generated during build. You need to clean and then rebuild your project. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: no tried this and still this problem. every new project i create in eclipse has this problem....ERROR: Unable to open class file C:\Users\Mat\workspace2\recorder\gen\com\tecmark\R.java: No such file or directory
[2011-01-30 10:40:26 - mm] ERROR: Unable to open class file C:\Users\Mat\workspace2\mm\gen\mm\mm\R.java: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the file and then rebuild your project (a clean build could help too).

Answer (score 0):

if you're having the problem for every new project, it could be this:

["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins/2196397#2196397)

that's what fixed it for me, even though I wasn't getting any debug certificate errors.  apparently the debug certificate is only valid for one year.