# Eclipse android project not running?

Tags: android, eclipse

Whenever I try to run an application on the emulator it says "Your project contains error(s),please fix them before running your application."Even when I try to run the default hello world program I get the same error.

Comment: You must be get solve using this link [enter link description here][1]. Please just read once time.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954316/your-project-contains-errors-please-fix-it-before-running-it