# Unknown error in Android project

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Debug certificate expired” error in eclipse android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

As you can see from my profile, I have programmed lots of Android projects already. However, I am now stuck, maybe due to the new Eclipse plugin or SDK version.

I created a new project for Android 1.6 and SDK 4. Once, I compile the build as it is, I see an error mark (X) in the project top element. However, there is neither a description, nor a quick fix available, and none of the project files display an error mark. I cannot run the project.

What is going on? How can I get any information about that error?

Thanks.

Comment: does clean project help?

Comment: Have you had a look at the problems view?  If you go to the windows menu, select show view, problems, it should take you to the problems view (it's usually at the bottom). That should have any errors listed in it.

Comment: Does an APK get generated after the build? What eclipse version are you using?

Comment: OK. I looked at the problems view. It says "debug certificate expired 17.4.11". So what is this?

Comment: I think I had the same problem a few days ago or at least with the same symptoms. In my case the problem was that the debug certificated was expired and has to be renewed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins

Comment: Yes that was it. What a rubbish! I will answer my question with this final answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. It took me about 5 hours to find out what the problem was.