# Android project not compiling, error in build path?

Tags: java, android

I wasn't really sure how to title this, but basically I am having an issue with something in my android build path or something. I have 2 projects, one of which worked before, and I haven't touched in since and now it won't compile either. Both projects just have an x on the folder saying there is an error in them somewhere, but none of the java files have errors flagged, and neither does the r.java. I figured someone might have had a similar problem and could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

WWaldo

Comment: Have you installed a new SDK version by any chance? If this is the case, there is usually an error on Console saying e.g. Unable to resolve target 'android-6', if you removed the old SDK, and you can fix these by updating an existing SDK version (target=) to default.properties file.

Comment: No, I haven't, and the only thing in the console came up when I cleaned, as I said in the comment in the answer down there somewhere

Comment: Ok. It shouldn't do any harm to make sure your projects are using an existing SDK though. If you right-click on your project and select 'Properties'. There you can find Android sheet, and check that there is a 'Project Build Target' selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: clean project in Eclipse or refresh project or both.
If still doesn't work, restart Eclipse.

**edited:**
Answer for your problem with debug certificate:
["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

And probably answer for missing gen and R.java file:
[R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: Tried cleaning, and one of the 2 of them now has an ! by it, and it says it is missing the r.java, even though it had one before the clean, and the other one didn't change at all with refreshing, cleaning, or restarting :(

Comment: Refreshing works fine with missing r.java file for me. Look into Problems tab in Eclipse to see reported problems.

Comment: Okay, I checked that, it said one of the projects debug certificate expired, not really sure what that means, I will look that up after I'm done typing this. The other says I am missing the gen folder, but it exists, I opened the r.java and everything, I don't understand that one

Comment: In case you didn't see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins) already. Might be the same issue you're facing.

Comment: I was able to fix the debug issue with what you posted, I am about try the other answer

Comment: Okay, I am only getting one problem now, it just says "The project cannot be built until the build path errors are resolved." with nothing else, I tried this http://www.scottdstrader.com/blog/ether_archives/000921.html but no luck, I am going to keep looking, thanks for all of your help so far

Comment: Okay, I reset the sdk source folder, and it all works now, thanks everyone!

Comment: Go to your PC OS drive EX."C:\Documents and Settings\user\.android" and delete "default.keyset" file