# Eclipse prevents compile on the basis of non-existent errors

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, build

I get:

> Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.

...when I try to compile and run my project.

Eclipse indicates no errors. The only warnings I have are asterisk imports.

Yes, I have tried cleaning and building the project, but to no avail.

The problem didn't even go away when I temporarily deleted the single source file I have (and then cleaned and built).

I've tried restarting Eclipse multiple times.

I doubt rebooting my computer will have any effect.

My Droid X is plugged in on USB for testing. Not sure if that would have any effect.

Things like these are really frustrating, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the problem by clicking `Problems` on bottom tab. If it's not there, open it by selecting `window > Show View > Problems`.

And paste the Error here, so I can know the real problem.. :)

[image: Problem]

Comment: AHAHA! Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 6/8/11 11:57 PM

With a google search I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins) thread. The problem is that my debug signature had expired. So deleting ~/.android/debug.keystore under my windows user account folder did the trick. Glad we figured this one out!

Comment: thats a common problem. The Annoying Invisible Problem :p
Glad I can help you ^^

Answer (score 2):

Can't tell you why this is happening, but here are some things I'd try:

- Close and reopen the project
- Delete and re-import the project
- Check that you're not filtering errors too narrowly (e.g. only selected resource)
- Go into build configuration and check that there are no unresolved project and library dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your comment, nothing worked though. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete .settings file. And then delete you project from workspace and re-import. Maybe that helps but thats just a guess :/

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the whole code and saved it in a seperate file. than save the empty file where the non-existing errors appear. now the problems are gone and you can copy the code back to the file :)