# Android "Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current Theme" error

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm writing a simple android application that should display google maps. The application displays the *"Activity is not responding"* error upon startup. In the `mapdisplay.xml` file where I define the map view activity, I get a  "Failed to find style *'mapViewStyle'* in current Theme" error message, so I think it's the reason behind the crash.

I have the Internet permission set and the *uses-library* tag placed correctly in the manifest.
Here is the code listing

```
public class OnthisdayActivity extends MapActivity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapdisplay);
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
{
    return false;
}
}
```

And the xml file mapdisplay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:enabled="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="xxxxxx"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="onthisday.main"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity android:name=".OnthisdayActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably because you are debbuging without the Google Maps API.

Comment: And how do I debug using the Google Maps API? I mean the library is included and all, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Create new project -> Select on Build Target one with Google APIs. Once created, in the project libraries, you should see the maps.jar along with the android.jar file.

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately. I had the maps.jar file before but I though maybe eclipse was not able to read it, but turns out that's not the problem.

Comment: Delete the R.java file and try a rebuild.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think it's got something to do with my mapdisplay.xml file since it does not build and it gives me this "Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme" error.

Comment: My development environment is Eclipse on Mac OS if that's of any help.

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975203/android-google-maps-failed-to-find-style-mapviewstyle-in-current-theme

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17209093/1979347