# Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?

Tags: android

> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout? Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references. Failed to find style `mapViewStyle` in current theme.

I tried every solutions available to solve this problem but nothing seems to work. I have included library in the manifest file. I even created style is styles.xml, I have chosen Google Apis build target as well.

Can somebody please give me a solution?

here is my **xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/AppTheme"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
     android:id="@+id/themap"
     style="@style/mapViewStyle"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:apiKey="here i have my key"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:enabled="true" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my **manifest** snippet:

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Second" />

    <activity android:name=".Third"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"/>
  </application>
```

here is my **style.xml** file

```
<resources>
    <style name="mapViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Sure it's not `@style/AppTheme` your missing?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I m new to Android development. It didn't solve the problem. I added AppTheme but I'm still getting the same error. I changed the whole application's theme to Theme.Light so that there won't be any more conflicts. But the problem still persists!!! I can't figure out how to overcome this problem.

Comment: When I run the application, it runs fine til the second activity but in the activity which displays maps, it displays "Unfortunately yourapp has stopped"

Comment: @DebeshAdhikari If your problem is solved, consider accepting the answer which helped you solve it

Comment: Changing `minSDKVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` file worked for me.

Comment: This issue happens sometimes you create too many projects. And I try everything I can do, it doesn't work. Finally I just restart my Android Studio, you know what, it works normally!

Answer (score 155):

For Android Studio (or IntelliJ IDEA),

If everything looks OK in your project and you're still receiving the error in your layouts, try to 'Invalidate caches & restart'.

Enjoy a coffee while Android Studio is recreating caches & indexes.

[image: how to invalidate cache & restart]

Comment: Thanks. For me the error occurred in IntelliJ IDEA when I upgraded from 13.0.3 to 13.1.4, and this fixed it.

Comment: Thnx, m new to Android Studio, and searching for this answer i found your one is exact what i needed.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem on Android Studio 1.0 RC 2, Windows 7.

Comment: This worked for me, running Android Studio 1.0.2, Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: Works for me on Android Studio on Mac.

Comment: Worked for Android Studio 1.5.1 on Windows 10

Comment: Worked for me AppTheme wasnt showing in the Theme editor, now it does.

Comment: Works for me on AndroidStudio 2.2 on Mac. Thanks~

Comment: I just Restarted Android Studio and worked for me. (If you want to save some time then try this first.)

Comment: It works, but if I change to another generic phone or tablet, the same Theme and the same message pops up :(

Comment: It works.  Enjoy a coffee while Android Studio is recreating caches & indexes  lol

Answer (score 154):

I had the same problem and found it was the Theme dropdown at the top of the graphical layout editor.  I changed from Holo to Theme and the layout displayed and error disappeared.

Comment: I changed it from "App Theme" to "App Compat" and that fixed it for me. BTW: grates are great at preventing kittens from being swept down into the sewer.

Comment: Your answer is worked for me.I check my theme in style,then I choose it in the layout too :)

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. I chosen "Holo.Light.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 14):

What I usually do is the following: a `Gradle Clean`, `Rebuild` and `Sync all my Gradle files`. After that I `restart` **Android Studio**, and I go to:

```
Select Theme -> Project Themes -> AppTheme
```

Answer (score 13):

This is because you select not a theme of your project. Try to do next:

[image]

Comment: Work for me, Thx.

Answer (score 8):

If we are creating too many projects using Android Studio sometime Rendering issue comes. Even creating a blank activity we receive such rendering error.
Please shut down and restart Android studio. In case the issue persists you can [image: Android Studio Cache Invalidation and Restart]

Hope this helps. It works similar fashion as rule of thumb, in case all looks good and still error persists a restart of application usually resolves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem occurred while the default setting for Android Version in the Designer was set to 'Preview N'. Changed Android Version to '23' and the error notification went away.
 
**Edit**
 And don't forget to uncheck 'Automatically Pick Best'.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using Android Studio 1.5.1.

This was solved by using the Android SDK Manager and updating *Android Support Library*, as well as *Local Maven repository for Support Libraries*.

[image]

After updating the SDK and **restarting** Android Studio, the problem was rectified.

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem after trying other suggestions.

Comment: I didn't try any of the other suggestion, went right to this one and my preview rendered without errors after updating SDK then restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by changing "classpath" in "dependencies" in build.gradles.

Just change:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha2'
```

or something like that to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after overriding action bar style like this. Also i lost action bar in preview.

```
<style name="general_app_theme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- for API level 11 -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/action_bar_style</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/action_bar_style</item>

</style>

<style name="action_bar_style" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- for API level 11 -->
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/action_bar_height</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="displayOptions">showTitle</item>
</style>
```

So, problem is overriding theme by my custom. this is the reason, why I've changed AppCompat (from "Project Themes") to general_app_theme (from "Manifest Themes"). Now I have no this error and action bar in preview come back.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the theme in the design view to one of the options in "Manifest Themes". I'm guessing this is Because you are inheriting the theme from the manifest to support multiple api levels. It worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to the answer provided by @Benno:
Instead of changing to a specific theme, you can simply choose 'DeviceDefault' from the theme menu. This should choose the theme most compatible with the emulated device.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the problem after trying all the solutions above， please try modify the API Level as shown below. Incorrect API Level may also cause the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with my customized theme that used Holo.Light as its parent. In grayed text Android Studio indicated that some attributes were missing. When I added these missing attributes as follows, the rendering problems went away -

```
    <item name="android:textEditSuggestionItemLayout"></item>
    <item name="android:textEditSuggestionContainerLayout"></item>
    <item name="android:textEditSuggestionHighlightStyle"></item>
```

Even though they introduced errors in my style's theme, they caused no problems in rendering the activity designs or building my app.

Comment: I spoke too soon - the screens rendered okay; however, I am getting 'No resource found' for the Container and Style lines'. Stay tuned.

Comment: Evidently the parent theme of android.'theme.Holo.Light' is missing these attributes and there is no documentation I can find to include them. I solved my problem by switching to the 'android.theme.Holo' theme.

Answer (score 1):

It can be fixed by changing your theme in **styles.xml** from 
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

and **clean the project**. It will surely help.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the errors in XML happen due to the names you have given to the resources.

Images stored in the drawable folder need to be named in a proper manner.
just check these things:

1. Are there any duplicate files? if so remove the duplicates. (For example `"image.jpg"` and `"image.png"` are not allowed in the same time. It will not show any errors but sometimes it will show that R.java cannot be resolved)
2. Do the filenames contains any uppercase letters? If so right click on that `file`->`refactor`->`rename`
   and rename it with all lowercase, no hyphens, and only a-z and 0-9 are allowed.

Just make sure of the above cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove this error through change "App theme" and select any theme such as light. This error will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem.Select theme to another one in preview can solve problem temporary.[Like the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq6oE.png)

Finally,I found out that there are `AppTheme` and `AppBaseTheme` in my styles.xml.
And `AppTheme` has parent  `AppBaseTheme`.
The  `AppBaseTheme` has parent of one system style.

And every layout file use the theme `AppTheme`.
Just change `AppTheme`'s parent to `AppBaseTheme`'s parent.
It solve the problem permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Just need click button '**AppTheme**', and choose '**Manifest Themes**'. It works in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was occurring on `menu.xml` file as i was using **android:Theme.Light** as my theme, So what i did was -

1. Added new Folder in res directory named values-v21.
2. Added **android:Theme.Material.Light** as AppTheme in `styles.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late but i like to share my experience this same issue.
i face the same issue in Android studio i tried to some other solution that i found in internet but nothing works for me unless i **REBUILD THE PROJECT** and it solve my issue.

Hope this will works for you too.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Change your App theme to AppCombat..
[image]