# NoSuchFieldException when field exists

Tags: java, reflection

I'm getting a `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException` when trying to run the following method:

```
 public void getTimes(String specialty, String day) {
    ArrayList<Tutor> withSpec = new ArrayList<Tutor>();
    for (Tutor t : tutorList){
        try {
            Time startTime = (Time)t.getClass().getField(day + "Start").get(t);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException ex) Logger.getLogger(DBHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); }
```

The error is on the line `Time startTime = (Time)t.getClass().getField(day + "Start").get(t);`

I don't understand this error, because monStart is a field of the `Tutor` class:

```
Public class Tutor implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "tutorID")
private Integer tutorID;

.... 

@Column(name = "monStart")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
 Date monStart;
```

I'm just learning to use reflection, so I'm sure this is some sort of a syntactical error...

Comment: Did it crash your app?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The [`getField`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getField(java.lang.String)) method will only find the field if it's `public`.  You will need to use the [`getDeclaredField`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)) method instead, which will find any field that is declared *directly* on the class, even if it's not `public`.

Comment: even after using getDeclaredField over getField iam getting this error :-         can not access a member of class  with modifiers "private"

Comment: ohh get it. i need to use setAccessible(true)

Comment: I am getting `NoSuchFieldException` even when using `getDeclaredField()`, and the "has private access" error even after using `setAccessible(true)`.

**Example 1**: `Field fieldy = rootElement.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");` throws `NoSuchFieldException`. But doing `Field[] fields = rootElement.getClass().getDeclaredFields();` allows me to iterate through the fields, and when I call `field.getName()`, it returns "name". So what's the deal?

Comment: **Solved**: Looks like I had to wrap in a try/catch

Comment: @JoeFlack how did surrounding with a `try/catch` solve anything? The Exception gets thrown anyways, and then what do you do in the `catch` to properly get that field which exists but somehow throws the `NoSuchFieldException` ?

Comment: If the field is inherited from a superclass, this answer won't be sufficient. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69946642/9768291

Answer (score 14):

According to the javadoc, `Class.getField()` "Returns a `Field` object that reflects the specified public member field of the class or interface represented by this `Class` object".
Use `getDeclaredField()` if you want to access non-public fields.

Answer (score 9):

For any Android developers seeing this that still can't seem to fix the issue, **check to see if Proguard is enabled.** If it is, it's possible the class in question is being obfuscated and you'll need to add rules to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My class was also getting obfuscated. I had to disable `minifyEnabled` flag in order to prevent it.

Answer (score 8):

Best solutions for `getClass().getField()` problem are:

1. Use **getDeclaredField**() instead of **getField**():

```java
        String propertyName = "test";
        Class.forName(this.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredField(propertyName);
```

2. Replace **"HelloWorld"** with your class name:

```java
        String propertyName = "name";
        HelloWorld.class.getDeclaredField(propertyName);
```

If you want to get the annotation length of the column:

```java
HelloWorld.class.getDeclaredField(propertyName).getAnnotation(Column.class).length();
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, using `getDeclaredField` will potentially solve your problem (in case the field wasn't declared as `public`).

If you are still getting the `NoSuchFieldException`, then it might be because that field is actually in the superclass! Indeed, if your class `extends` another class, then you will not get the inherited fields through the `getDeclaredField` method. Here is how to fix that problem:

```java
String propertyName = "foo";
yourClass.getClass().getSuperClass().getDeclaredField(propertyName);
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: How do I set a value for an inherited field? I get `NoSuchFieldException` when I try `field.set(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I came to this question based on the title. I was getting the same error (`NoSuchFieldException`) in my Android project but for a different reason.

So for others who come here, this error can also potentially be caused by the caches getting out of sync in Android Studio. Go to **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439486/missing-styles-is-the-correct-theme-chosen-for-this-layout) also