# NoSuchFieldException when trying to retrieve the value of field

Tags: java, class, reflection, field, nosuchfileexception

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420968/nosuchfieldexception-when-field-exists) post and followed the `guidelines` there. but that did not help; I get `NoSuchFieldException` when the field exists. The sample `code` is below:

Here is my code:

```
class A{
    private String name="sairam";
    private int number=100;
} 
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class cls = Class.forName("A");
    Field testnum=cls.getDeclaredField("number"); 
    testnum.setAccessible(true);
    int y = testnum.getInt(testnum);
    System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

EDIT: per answer below, I tried this:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("A");
    Field testnum=cls.getDeclaredField("number");
    testnum.setAccessible(true);
    A a = new A();
    int y = testnum.getInt(a);
    System.out.println(y);
```

but the error is same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Object` parameter of [Field#getInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getInt%28java.lang.Object%29) must be an instance of `class A`.

```
A a = new A();
int y = testnum.getInt(a);
```

Since the `name` and `number` fields are not static, you cannot get them from the class; you must get them from a particular instance of the class.

Comment: that did not help. did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It works. You still need the other parts of the code, such as `setAccessible(true)`.

Comment: I tried it.  It works.  You need to put the "new" line at the top of main, and replace the "int y=" line  with the one provided.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the "new" line is, as long as it is before the "int y=" line.

Comment: @DavidConrad: please see my edit above. I tried as you suggested but it fails. if my code above is wrong, please paste what you tried.

Comment: I just copied the code from your edit, and it works for me with Java 1.7.0_40. What error are you getting? Is it possible you have some other A.class on your classpath?

Comment: You could also use `A.class` or `new A().getClass()` instead of `Class.forName("A")` to make sure you are getting the right class. What line is the exception being thrown on?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is exactly as above, there shouldn't be any `NoSuchFieldException`. But there will be probably an `IllegalAccessException`. You should pass an instance of the class to `getInt()`:

```
int y = testnum.getInt(cls.newInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 int y = testnum.getInt(new A());
```

Instead of

```
int y = testnum.getInt(testnum);
```

Because the method wants as a parameter the **object** (the object of class `A`, not a `Field` class which you are using)to extract