# NoSuchFieldExpression when Debbugging

Tags: kotlin, debugging, testing, intellij-idea, mockito

Since a while I got the following Exception, when running my tests in Debugging Mode.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: serialPersistentFields
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2642)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSerialFields(ObjectStreamClass.java:1634)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialFields(ObjectStreamClass.java:1608)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:398)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:384)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:384)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1.computeValue(ObjectStreamClass.java:110)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1.computeValue(ObjectStreamClass.java:107)
at java.base/java.io.ClassCache$1.computeValue(ClassCache.java:73)
at java.base/java.io.ClassCache$1.computeValue(ClassCache.java:70)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(ClassValue.java:228)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(ClassValue.java:210)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.get(ClassValue.java:116)
at java.base/java.io.ClassCache.get(ClassCache.java:84)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:363)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:246)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier.<clinit>(TestIdentifier.java:51)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.<clinit>(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:72)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:383)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:376)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.getAgentClass(JUnitStarter.java:244)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:225)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

I am already, found the following links:

[NoSuchFieldException when field exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420968/nosuchfieldexception-when-field-exists)

I also created a Bug Report at:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-300566

Even running a simpleTest like:

```
package com.example.package

import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class SampleTest {
    @Test
    fun someTest(){
        //Arrange
        val a = 5
        val b = 10
        //Act
        val res = a + b
        //Assert
        res.shouldBe(15)
    }
}
```

causes the Exception shown above.

Does anyone got this problem alread and found a solution for it.
I am not serializing anything. I can't even debug the most simple Test, printing Hello World.
I a other project it's still possible.
After this exception there are coming a lot more and if I disable the Breakpoints the test is excecuted without problems.

Comment: Please provide more details, like the code part which produces the error, the test & productive code. Otherwise it is very hard to get you a proper response

Comment: The problem is that it suddently happens, it happens even in a really simple Test class like the one given above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that disabling exception breakpoints fix the problem for the moment.
Hope that there will be a better solution than this in the future.

The exceptions seem not to disturb the functionality of the Unit Test, so after all exceptions thrown the Breakpoints inside the code are visited again.