# Android Studio: Rendering Problems Missing styles-correct theme chosen for this layout, Failed to find style with id

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml, android-theme

I want to create card item xml layout for `CardView` and getting this error. [Common solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439486/missing-styles-is-the-correct-theme-chosen-for-this-layout) not worked (tried them all and others from similar posts).

This is my `xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp">


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the relevant part of `styles.xml`:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_accent</item>
</style>

<!--Theme for Tool Bar (Action Bar)-->
<style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

This is the relevant part from the `Manifest`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

This is the relevant part from `gradle build` script:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
```

And this is the error:

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: try changing the android api level in preview area. Try using api level 22.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue. Please restart Android Studio by selecting the menu option "File" → "Invalidate Caches / Restart". For more details please follow the link:

http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/harvesthq/chosen/q/stackoverflow/13439486/missing-styles-is-the-correct-theme-chosen-for-this-layout

Comment: @viper Check if Android studio version and  version inside build.gradle of your project are matching or not. dont confuse this with build.gradle of app. This maybe the issue in your case. If they are not matching, make sure they match and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 14):

You can solve this problem by changing current theme to suitable themes. Every theme is not suitable for every type of view. By using theme combobox we can solve this.
**Here is the problem**
[image]


**1. Firstly go theme bar and press it**

[image]

**2. Change your theme like in the picture below**
[image]
Now you changed your theme. If selected theme is suitable with your view it will render.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same error, what i did is i made the layout theme similar to the theme i am having in manifest.xml and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I face a similar issue what I did was click on Refresh button.[image]

If the problem still persists try Invalidate Caches and restart