# Rendering Problems error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a problem that I am having trouble solving. I installed Android Studio with correct ways. When I put a widget in the project, it gives this error and the Gradle processing doesn't finish and its working on button. What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: Did you download the appropriate libraries from SDK Manager?

Comment: try this answer on stackoverflow... http://stackoverflow.com/a/33643777/3678308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this number 8 to 23. it will most probably solve your issue

[image]

Comment: then try cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: it didn't fix again