# Android Studio Rendering Error: Missing Styles

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

I'm trying to learn Android through the tutorials at TheNewBoston.com. 
In the tutorial, I'm supposed to switch to the **material light** theme. That's when I get the error. It says:

> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for the layout?

Here's a screen shot:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's what I've tried:

1. I've tried switching out of `Android API 23`, N preview for a lower
   API
2. I've tried changing code in the `styles.xml` file from

   `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

   to

   `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`
3. I've tried invalidating the cache and restarting.

Nothing seems to be working. I'm very new at Android and just want to get the IDE set up correctly. I also get this message on startup and I think it's related to the error:

[image: Related Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Android Studio and right-clicking the shortcut to run the program as administrator sorted out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your layout Preview from API N to API 23. also select target and compile sdk version 23.

[image]

Change Compile sdk version and Build SDK version

[image]

Comment: Sorry, how do I select target and compile under a different version?

Comment: go to file> Project structure > select app > Select Property tab > and select  Compile sdk version and Build sdk version to 23. Android N is currently not appropriate for development.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately the problem persists

Comment: You also need to change your Layout preview API to 23.  Go to Your layout> Select Preview> Then select API 23 level on top.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this line to your build.gradle file under dependencies

```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

Note that the support version number might be higher for you. Add below line too to your depedencies

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

Comment: Currently under build.gradle(Module:app)'s dependencies I have 23.2.1. I tried putting in your code, but no dice :-(

Comment: Did you try clicking on automatically add all missing attributes. Seems like some of your views are missing height and width.

Comment: Yea, I click it and nothing happens.

Comment: this is weird... Did you update android studio? Check if there are any updates for it. It might not be related but who knows

Comment: Tried updating - says I'm up to date. Currently have 25.0.10 Build number AI-143.2682552

Answer (score 0):

In theme dropdown at the top of the graphical display of layout. **change  Theme.**

check your theme in style than choose it in the layout too

OR

**changed from Holo to Theme and the layout displayed and error disappeared.**

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439486/missing-styles-is-the-correct-theme-chosen-for-this-layout) for more detail

Comment: what theme you have currently ?

Comment: check your theme in style,then choose it in the layout too.@TaylorLiss

Comment: AppTheme works, but if I try any of the other themes (Material Light, Holo Light, etc.) they don't work.

Comment: that is because that doest exist in your styles.xml.

Comment: check your theme in style and than apply that too. it will solve your issue.

Comment: In styles.xml it says <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: it doest exist ? or what error you are getting now ? @TaylorLiss