# Failed to update existing theme for activity

Tags: android, runtime, android-theme

I see this error when I execute my code:

```
E/InstantRun: Failed to update existing theme for activity com.example.android.getup.MainActivity@1ebe5a1
          java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mTheme in class Landroid/content/res/Resources$Theme; (declaration of 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
              at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
              at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources(MonkeyPatcher.java:374)
              at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.restart(Server.java:523)
              at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.access$600(Server.java:61)
              at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerReplyThread.handle(Server.java:318)
              at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerReplyThread.run(Server.java:190)
              at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerThread.run(Server.java:158)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

what does it mean?

### MainActivity.java

In general the app is an alarm app if its important and it's called GetUp

```
package com.example.android.getup;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.getup.Animations.ResizeAnimation;
import com.example.android.getup.Interfaces.FragmentCommunicator;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentCommunicator{

private TextView displayTime, displayMonthYear, displayDayName;
BroadcastReceiver _broadcastReceiver;
private final SimpleDateFormat _sdfWatchTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialization
    displayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_time);
    displayMonthYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_month_year);
    displayDayName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_day_name);

    // Setting up the day of the month
    displayTime.setText(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));
    displayMonthYear.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    setDisplayDayName();

    // The coolest button ever :)
    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    final View myView = findViewById(R.id.ll_reveal);
    myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    /**
     *
     * When the fab is clicked
     *
     * **/
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        boolean expandOrCollapse = true; // Seeing if adding alarm panel needs to be extended or collapsed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (expandOrCollapse) { // If the panel is extended
                ResizeAnimation.expand(myView); // Expand animation
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_clear_white_48dp, MainActivity.this.getTheme())); // Changing the fab's icon
                } else {
                    fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_clear_white_48dp));
                }

                expandOrCollapse = false; // Next time the fab is clicked, it'll collapse the add alarm panel

            }else{
                ResizeAnimation.collapse(myView);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_alarm_add_white_48dp, MainActivity.this.getTheme()));
                } else {
                    fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_alarm_add_white_48dp));
                }
                expandOrCollapse = true;
            }


    }
});
}

/**
 * The system will send this broadcast event at the exact beginning of every minutes based on system clock.
 **/
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    _broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)
                displayTime.setText(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));

    };

    registerReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (_broadcastReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
}

private void setDisplayDayName(){
    String Day = "";
    switch (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)){
        case 1: Day = "Sunday"; break;
        case 2: Day = "Monday"; break;
        case 3: Day = "Tuesday"; break;
        case 4: Day = "Wednesday"; break;
        case 5: Day = "Thursday"; break;
        case 6: Day = "Friday"; break;
        case 7: Day = "Saturday"; break;
    }
    displayDayName.setText(Day);

}

@Override
public void response(String[] alarmInfo) {
    AlarmsListFragment alarmsListF = (AlarmsListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.alarm_box_container_fragment);
    alarmsListF.onRecvData(alarmInfo);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

If you need more code let me know because im not sure what is necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

When I was getting this error, I solved it in Android Studio by going to **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...**.

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25421526/3681880)