# Navigation Drawer didn't create successfully

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have updated to Android Studio 3.1.2.I just created navigation drawer activity. But when I go into the activity_main_drawer.xml file,it's keep saying waiting for build to finish even after a build has already finished.how can i solve this problem? I just try 6 times but have same result.

Comment: If it says waiting for build to finish you only need to wait. Android Studio is heavy af to run. What are your pc specs? If you think that your pc is fine just try downgrading to a old version

Comment: See this [navigation drawer issue (not showing layout preview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201356/navigation-drawer-issue-not-showing-layout-preview/50221647#50221647)

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez Specs are fine.after i upgrade to 3.1.2 this problem came.

Comment: @mTak same result have :(

Comment: See my answer for a workaround not solution if you did not get it by the link

Comment: @mTak it's temporary work.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio can behave like that sometimes. Either you have to wait or try reinstalling Android Studio all together. Or, you can try and cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing on your activity yet, just create another navigation drawer activity. Or, just clean then rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for temporary workaround:

1. Remove `tools:showIn="navigation_view"`
2. Close `activity_main_drawer.xml`
3. Reopen it and go to design tab, wait 2-3secs

You will see your menu but as a regular menu.