# Component not showing in design view for navigation drawer android studio

Tags: android-studio, navigation-drawer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycsr2.png)

I am having some problems in displaying the component in navigation drawer. Although my code does not have any problem but the navigation drawer displays nothing. 
drawer_menu is component inside navigation drawer. Activity_main is navigation drawer itself

## activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

## drawer_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="Home"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="Profile"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:title="Setting"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_offer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_offer"
            android:title="Offer"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_off"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_off"
            android:title="Logout"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: try without group and use relative layout

Comment: Refer these example https://medium.com/quick-code/android-navigation-drawer-e80f7fc2594f

Comment: but the image I display is actually an android resource file and I did it the same way like the link u provided still the file display words instead of components

Comment: Attach your code

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin actually it is just not showing in preview design only, but when I run it appears.

Comment: OK, please attach relevant code to see I have the same problem or not

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin attached

Comment: Do you have implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' in build.gradle(:app)?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin yes

Comment: Always you see navigationview this way or just sometimes?

Comment: always in preview but in run mode it appears.

Comment: This answer helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201356/navigation-drawer-issue-not-showing-layout-preview