# How to solve Android studio 3.1.3 start up errors

Tags: java, android-studio

When I launch Android Studio 3.1.3 version, I select empty activity and then go into the studio. But when I haven't start coding yet, here comes 3 errors. I don't even start editing yet then got errors already. What logic is that? Can you guys help me?

Errors are embedded here:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run your app? The error may be fixed when the app run for the first time. The other two are only informative messages.

Comment: Please add the error message as text to your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50889156/edit) it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below line to your Application Theme:

```
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
```

Reference:[Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme)

Comment: where is the application theme

Comment: Check your styles.xml.

Answer (score -1):

add this line above your main java code:

```
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
```