# CoordinatorLayout not working in Android Studio 3.1.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I know this question has been asked a lot of times but I have tried most of the solutions, and none worked for me.
This is the first time that I'm working on android studio 3.1.3, and I was following a tutorial on how to create a simple app using the basic template option from the android studio. The problem that I'm facing is;
[image]

> Render Problem Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in
>   current theme

I have tried adding this to the build.gradle file:

> compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'

Also this into the style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.notes"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49305312/7551190)  helped me solve such similar problem. Give it a try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I tried following steps [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme/), but still the problem persists. I think it is a common issue in android studio 3.0+, Hopefully they will fix it next update. In the Android Studio Preview 3.2 it works fine. [Download Android Studio Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) and [visit here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview) to learn how to run it alongside with Android Studio stable version

[image]

Or you can try to lower your design library version to 27. (And the compile sdk version also to 27)

```
dependencies { implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2' implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "Base" before Theme in styles.xml as show : - "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Answer (score 1):

Permanent solution for this problem: change your build gradle (module app) to  implementation `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1`.

Answer (score 0):

change your build gradle (module app) 
from : com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1-alpha3

to : com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Comment: Can you explain why downgrading a dependency would fix the problem?

Comment: @Bajirang The dependencies version should match the compileSdkVersion. So downgrading to 27 would also require the OP to downgrade the compileSdkVersion. Instead, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49305312/7551190)  which helped me solve such similar problem

Answer (score 0):

1.try this first : make changes in Gradle (module app) for appcompat:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

2. If it doesn't work clean your project and then again build it.
In my case, it worked.