# I have this problems with the Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

The preview isn't showing anything.

[image]

and also shows many errors
1.Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
2.Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
3.The following classes could not be instantiated:

> - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this
>   is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then
>   manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener Copy stack to clipboard

Answer (score 1):

This question is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme) question. Since, I cannot comment, here is the accepted answer to the question:

I solved this rendering problem by simply inserting this line into the application theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
 </style>
```