# How do you fix android...Coordinator Layout in the latest version of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

As you can see, this is what appears when I start a new Android Studio Project.[image: ![enter image description here]
I've tried multiple method to get it to say the default "Hello World" instead. I've tried the 60+ upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme) but that didn't work as I get a cannot resolve error. One of the comments for that answer suggested using

> @style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout

and I put that there.

[image]

Nevertheless, I still get android...CoordinatorLayout.

Here is my app gradle
[image]
After invalidating I get this screen below
[image]

EDIT: ADDED GRADLE
EDIT: ADDED INVALIDATION IMAGE

Comment: Can you please share your app gradle file

Comment: @EldhoPJames Added it. It appears to be the default one so I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: Did you try to invalidate and restart?

Comment: Sorry can you explain how to do that in Android Studio. I just installed it today.

Comment: Go to File -->  Click on Invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: @Qwerty Qwerts did invalidate and restart  solved your problem?

Comment: @pie no it didn't help. I posted new image to post showing what I get

Answer (score 0):

Android sdk 28 have issues with displaying constant layout

I suggest you to revert back to latest stable of sdk version 27

Happy*Coding*