# Android Studio blank CoordinatorLayout designer

Tags: android

I just started an Android Studio project and on the center of the Design of the MainActivity the is written "android...CoordinatorLayout".

[image: Android Studio Issue - Screenshot]

Comment: Already a solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme)

Answer (score 0):

To use Coordination layout
Add this dependency
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0' to gradle (module)
(According to your android studio version and sdk. You can check any video to watch how to add dependcy) and then sync it

If you already did this then the problem is present in you xml code. Please put the text xml code in this post.