# Android Studio Render Problem: Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Whenever I add Navigation Activity I am getting this issue below is screenshot attached. For more details, I am using compile SDK version 27.
I am getting this issue in layout files generated after adding navigation activity.

My theme is AppTheme.NoActionBar

My styles.xml file content is below:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

What to do? I am pretty much stuck on this.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme)

Answer (score 0):

I think use(Base.Theme) Your Problem is Solved
like this :parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">