# Missing styles in xml layouts

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-theme

I face big problem in my app in android studio this massage appear in xml and i try to clear cash and restart but still appear `Missing styles`. **Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?**  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

> Failed to find style 'scrollViewStyle' in current theme (4 similar errors not shown)
>   Style with id 0x7f0900d1 (resolved to 'CardView_Light') does not exist.
>   Style with id 0x7f0900d1 (resolved to 'CardView_Light') does not exist.

[image: this is image of problem]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439486/missing-styles-is-the-correct-theme-chosen-for-this-layout)

Comment: @Mahmoud Elgamal which theme you are using? update your style.xml and layout  xml

Answer (score 0):

> Select Theme -> Project Themes -> AppTheme

You Need to set appropriate `Theme` for particular `layout` also make sure you are using correct API level.

- You need to `Gradle` Clean, Rebuild and Sync all `Gradle` files.
- Then restart `Android` Studio

Comment: you need to set the theme by clicking on AppTheme button top of the error window

Comment: I select theme but no result

Comment: which API level  are you using??