# Failed to find style 'bottomNavigationStyle' in current theme

Tags: android

I am a beginner in using android studio. I don't know why all types of containers such as bottomnavigationview, tablayout, navigationview and others give the same error which is failing to find the style in the current theme. I have used the latest SDK version. I have also tried to change the theme and still have an error. It also has an error "failed to instantiate one or more classes"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.etflin.etflin"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'}
```

This is the code from the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ChatRoom">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371166/failed-to-find-style-mapviewstyle-in-current-theme)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution that works for me:

In Build.gradle after dependencies add:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "27.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found this on Stack,
You can check it out , it was named as the Theme error: [Theme Error - how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017363/theme-error-how-to-fix)