# Theme Error - how to fix?

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Tried Many Solution But No Helped

Ref : [Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme/51091869#51091869)

But not Helped

> Render Problem:
>
> Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme
>
> Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

build.gradle file of my project is :

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*****"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

main Activity XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:fabAttached="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="12dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Why I am Not changing compiled SDK version 28 to 27
bcz I want to use Bottom app bar

[Bottom App Bar Material Design](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/)

[App Bars:Bottom- Material Design](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html)

[image: Main Activity Xml]

Comment: Add this library `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` as well to your module:app, respectively the one corresponding to your sdk

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with the latest support library version although i am not really sure.. So try replacing your current version to 27.1.1 and see if it works. compileSdkVersion 27 targetSdkVersion 27 and implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

Comment: when changed design and apcompat virsion i got

Comment: error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar (aka *.appbar:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar) not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar (aka **.appbar:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar) not found., sources=[/home/android/Desktop/Android Studio Projects/Appbar/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:10], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Comment: This is happening because Material Components have not yet shipped new releases under the dependency version 27 as of yet. So You'll have to copy the portions of the Material Components library you want directly into your project if you want access to the latest changes.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015248/4824088 will help you..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme In Android Studio 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856622/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme-in-android-studio)

Comment: Just use the canary version of android studio Here is the link https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/

Comment: I already search about this question

Comment: but I want to use bottom app bar so

Comment: it necessary to use compiled sdk v. 28 or android-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in 28.0.0 and the only fix(workaround) is adding this to your `Build.gradle`:

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Which somehow, this bypasses the issue and uses 27 support library for that. Otherwise, you may wanna update your Android Studio to canary channel version or using backward support library like 27.1.1 or etc.

Comment: Android studio updated to canary channel virsion Thanks

Comment: I tried 5 solutions and this is the only that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This error was occurred in your Rendering Layout which is a part of Studio Not in any files or Library

1. Try adding "Base" before Theme in styles.xml as show : -
   "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
2. Please restart Android Studio by selecting the menu option "File" →
   "Invalidate Caches / Restart"
3. Workarounds: Try rendering with M preview using AS v1.3 preview OR
   use FrameLayout for designing and change to
   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout while debugging.

Comment: still not work i alredy try this solution Invalidate Caches/ Restart

Comment: try to replace implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1' to  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'

Comment: After that Do Clean and Rebuild the project

Comment: still not working tried implementation of 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'