# Android Studio design view not displaying correctly

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I have looked at numerous sites and the suggestions provided here at Stack Overflow. Everything works fine with my Android Studio, except the design view does not display anything. I can drag and drop widgets or modify the XML code by hand and the text gets updated fine, but the changes just don't register on the design or blueprint. I have tried deleting and reinstalling the IDE, changing the SDK version, doing build--> clean, resetting the cache, and adding dependencies. Below is my build.gradle Anyone with a critical eye have suggestions? I don't know what I'm doing.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mydrinkmixer.somerestaurant.mydrinkmixer"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-  android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }

   dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Hello CAT, welcome to the Stackoverflow. Please mention the errors in your question from the **preview** tab using the error icon(or simply pressing  _E_ with focus on the preview tab.

Comment: Hello, the project builds perfectly fine with no errors presented. The issue is I the design/blueprint views don't display anything when they should. So I can't see what my activities look like when I format them

Comment: Which version of android studio you are using? Also check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020244/4409113 There is a bug with `28.0.0-rc02` version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Theme Error - how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017363/theme-error-how-to-fix)

Comment: I'm using version 28. Adding that code posted in those links to my gradle file seems to have fixed the issue! Thanks