# LayoutEditor java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with latest AndroidStudio and API 28

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Premise: I have already tried all solutions proposed in Stackoverflow similar questions where is suggested to rebuild, clean cache, or add to the style parent `Base.` with no result. So the error should have a different cause also because happens on project with the latest API level 28.

The editor doesn't work reporting that the following classes could not be instantiated:

- **android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout**
- **android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout**

Error stack:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image]

Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lore.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: I've had this happen a lot recently. Sometimes an "Invalidate Caches/Restart" works, sometimes nothing does and it just randomly starts working again a few days later. I've mostly just given up on the design view for now.

Comment: @TheWanderer nope I have tried many times and also totally cleared the whole Android Studio folders trying a clean setup

Comment: Like I said, sometimes it just doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it's an Android Studio bug. Have you tried the 3.2 RC or 3.3 Canary? Or even IntelliJ?

Comment: @TheWanderer I'm using the latest version already officially released. I haven't tried if the preview versions have the same issue.

Comment: `28.0.0-rc` and `alpha` version of `28` dependency had the same problem and it sounds like the preview issue still persist in the stable version of 28. As you know, using 27.1.1 was the workaround or my answer [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020244/4409113) but however, using the latest version of Android studio like Canary version should solve it.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Check the gradle script piece posted above. I have used the latest release version. NOT rc or alpha.

Comment: Yes I have checked that: `it sounds like the preview issue still persist **in the stable version of 28**` But it worked on my side just now somehow. Pretty weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today has been officially released the latest (and till now Release Candidate)

```
Android Studio 3.2
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, built on September 17, 2018
```

and `build tools 2.0.3`

In these versions the bug of Layout Editor not working with API 28 has been fixed. Install the updated IDE and tools, edit the gradle script accordingly end resync the project.