# Failed to find style ... in current theme

Tags: android, android-layout, render

I've faced a questionable error during my work with android studio.
Everytime I start studio and create a new project there is another render error

> Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

I do not clearly understand what does it mean, but it is easy to deal with it via replacing

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

but evertime I add new element to the layout, there is error

> Failed to find style ... in current theme
>   [image: Layout Theme = AppTheme]

I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371166/failed-to-find-style-mapviewstyle-in-current-theme), that helped almost everybody except me. But changing theme now doesn't solve the problem.

If anybody know how to deal with it please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the style name `floatingactionbuttonstyle` and included it in your apptheme.

Add this line

```
<item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton</item>
```

And finally theme look like this

```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton</item>

</style>
```

> **Just add the style name when error occured in layout editor & add the responding styles**.

Here some other few elements am added in styles for others.

```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip</item>
    <item name="chipGroupStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ChipGroup</item>
    <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView</item>
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout</item>
    <item name="bottomAppBarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar</item>
    <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton</item>
</style>
```

You can add default style with style name. Then you resolve this error.

Comment: @Flammifer Welcome glad to help..!

Answer (score 0):

In your app gradle under dependencies use this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

if you heven't already.