# Android - Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, google-maps

I've a little problem with my Android Maps Application. So that when I added MapView to my layout xml file it shows me "Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme" error message.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.acilSRV.client"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity android:name=".AcilActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```

And main.xml where that error message appears:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/myMapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="*******"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: I have already checked my Google Maps api key and there's no problem with api key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you selected a build target that includes GoogleApis?

Comment: yes, Google Apis - 10 (2.3.3 version)

Comment: possible mirror of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975203/android-google-maps-failed-to-find-style-mapviewstyle-in-current-theme

Comment: I've already tried all this solutions that error still appears...

Comment: try to build with ant to clearify if it's an Eclipse Bug

Comment: Btw when I type "keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore" into terminal I get "Enter keystore password:" prompt and when I type Enter, it shows me Warning message before showing up a fingerprint...The Warning message is: "The integrity of the information stored in your keystore has NOT been verified!In order to verify its integrity,you must provide your keystore password."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were right, Rafael T, that's an Eclipse bug...I have solved this using Ant builder (through terminal), and that worked :) Thanks again..

Comment: do you have the latest eclipse-release?

Comment: I am experiencing it with Juno 4.3 .. Latest Platform tools.. :S

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too.. go into res>values>styles.xml

remove the previous theme line and put this one

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
```

During the project creation, Eclipse asks to define a theme for the application. You might have selected any Holo theme. This theme doesn't support MapView which is showing the error.