# Let's solve the "Failed to find style 'mapViewstyle' in current theme" error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-mapview

Sorry to post yet another one of these, but it seems we have yet to document every solution to this issue.

Here's what happened: I added a mapview, everything was working peachy. I added a slidingdrawer and moved buttons into it, then changed the root node from a linear to a relative. Since then I get an error in the Graphical Layout of my main.xml class that reads

> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout? Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references. Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme.

Toggling the root node to linear and back to relative has gotten the map to display, but the error is still in the graphical layout.

So far I have done the following solutions, which may resolve the issue for most cases:

1. Added a style.xml to create a 'mapView' style.
2. Verified my build target is API 2.3.3 (10)
3. Made sure `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` is a child node of Application.
4. Clean/rebuilt my application.
5. Deleted R.
6. Deleted and rebuilt main.xml
7. Restarted the adb server, Eclipse, my computer, and my device.
8. Toggled between Android 3.0 and Android 2.3.3 in the Graphical Layout.

However, my problem persists. Here's my layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    style="@style/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:apiKey="asdf" //not my real key
    android:clickable="true" />

<!-- TODO: update the API key with release signature -->
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Menu" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/about"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/about" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/record"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/record" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start" />

    </LinearLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my manifest xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.myschoolhere"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".GeoTagActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

If anyone has a solution, please let me know. I'll do my best to post back if I ever figure it out.

Comment: Do you want style="@style/mapView" in your MapView or was that just a typo?

Comment: `@style` and `@styles` throw the same error. What's the correct syntax to reach /values/style.xml?

Comment: Have you seen this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371166/failed-to-find-style-mapviewstyle-in-current-theme, in particular the last answer.

Comment: I did, but it wasn't one of the steps I listed. I'll add it.

Comment: @Billdr Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry @Mosquito. I was able to work around it, but the GUI designer constantly shows an error.

Comment: Thanks for the info :-) I managed to find a reason for this error in my case after several hours - it was because I had an apostrophe character inside `<string> </string>`.

Comment: check this answer [Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17209093/1979347

Answer (score 10):

My answer may be a late one, but i hope that it'll deals with the actual reason and sure it could be helpful for those who are going to search about the same problem in future.

This type of errors,

```
1. Android Google Maps Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme
2. Failed to find style 'imageButtonStyle' in current theme 
3. Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme 
4. Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme
```

Anything from the above list it may be,

The ultimate reason is ,

We have selected the unavailable `Theme` for the `layout`.

This may cause because of,

1. The selected `theme` is not available in `themes.xml` file.
2. The selected `theme` is belongs to higher version `sdk`, but our current target `sdk` is lower one.

This problem mostly happens,

1. when you copy the whole `layout` file and try to implement it in your `project`.
   a. Your may forgot to copy `themes.xml` file
   b. You may have lower `target  sdk`, the original `layout` created with higher `target sdk`.

The Solutions for this problem are,

(**Open** and **View** the `layout` file in the `Graphical Layout View`, and look at the top Right corner.
There your `themes` for the `layout` have been selected.)

1. So click the dropdown list for `theme` selection and choose the available `themes` according to your project `themes` and `targeted sdk themes`.
                          **(OR)**
2. If the `theme` is a `custom` one , if you are required it , then copy the `themes.xml` file to your project from the source where you copied the `layout xml` file.
                          **(OR)**
3. If the `theme` is `sdk` avail `theme`, if you are required it , then change your `target` according to your selected `theme`.

Hope,This might be helpful for somebody.

Comment: This looks like solid information. I'll try to take a look at it this afternoon.

Comment: This did not solve the problem in my case. My theme is not customized. As noted in points 2 and 8, my target and theme selection are the same. I'm using the Theme.NoTitlebar; switching to other themes did not resolve the issue.

Comment: This is an exact copy of your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513278/android-failed-to-find-style-mapviewstyle-in-current-theme. This issue is not related to the themes.xml, as the theme is inherited from the Maps API.

Answer (score 4):

**This solution is for Android Studio maybe it will give an idea for Eclipse user too.**
Every android theme is not suitable for every view. Because of this we should select one of the suitable themes for our view type.

**Here is how problems looks**
If theme is not suitable it will give us missing styles error.

[image]


**Here is the solution**

1.Firstly select theme bar.

[image]

2.Select theme for your view

[image]

3.After selecting theme then press ok.
 If the theme is suitable for your view it will render if not then select another theme and try until you find a suitable theme for your application.
Whenever your theme is suitable it will render as like the picure below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue.

I don't know what the problem was and after searching an answer on google I found nothing of help.

So What I did was deleted the activity and guess what??, it worked.

Again, I'm not sure how did this work out but it did eventually for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

when you create android application,you choose minimum required sdk API14.And then,you will create project successfully.This is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Refresh button [image]

Else Try Invalidate Caches and Restart