# Android maps:Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I am trying to use maps in my application and i get this error,
Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme

i have generated the key properly, and have tried all solutions offered for the same problem at other places.

```
1.my target api and the one mentioned in the manifest file are the same.
2.There is no import.R in my project
3.I have cleaned my project.
4.Uses-library element is a child of the application.
```

This is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="*****************" 
        android:enabled="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my corresponding java file

package com.epidemicator.prototype;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class Mapacti extends MapActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

please help me out here...
thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975203/android-google-maps-failed-to-find-style-mapviewstyle-in-current-theme?

Comment: I agree with dmon see the question he/she references and look at the docs http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#useslibrary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer may be a late one, but i hope that it'll deals with the actual reason and sure it could be helpful for those who are going to search about the same problem in future.

This type of errors,

```
1. Android Google Maps Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme
2. Failed to find style 'imageButtonStyle' in current theme 
3. Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme 
4. Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme
```

Anything from the above list it may be,

The ultimate reason is ,

We have selected the unavailable `Theme` for the `layout`.

This may occur because of the following reasons,

1. The selected `theme` is not available in `themes.xml` file.
2. The selected `theme` is belongs to higher version `sdk`, but our current target `sdk` is lower one.

This problem mostly happens,

1. when you copy the whole `layout` file and try to implement it in your `project`.
   a. Your may forgot to copy `themes.xml` file
   b. You may have lower `target  sdk`, the original `layout` created with higher `target sdk`.

The Solutions for this problem are,

(**Open** and **View** the `layout` file in the `Graphical Layout View`, and look at the top Right corner.
There your `themes` for the `layout` have been selected.)

1. So click the dropdown list for `theme` selection and choose the available `themes` according to your project `themes` and `targeted sdk themes`.
                          **(OR)**
2. If the `theme` is a `custom` one , if you are required it , then copy the `themes.xml` file to your project from the source where you copied the `layout xml` file.
                          **(OR)**
3. If the `theme` is `sdk` avail `theme`, if you are required it , then change your `target` according to your selected `theme`.

Hope - This might be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add this little tidbit. I was getting error #4 above. It took me forever to realize that the theme I had made for my `Preferences` was automatically being applied to every single layout file I had already made. Choosing a different one as described above fixed my problem. I don't know why Android Studio automatically applied it to all my other layouts, but I wish it wouldn't.

I still don't know why the theme I'd made was breaking everything, as it was only applying a backgroundColor to my `Preferences` page, but hopefully someday I will.