# Failed to load properties file...NOT AGAIN :(

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I updated the ADT plugin recently and my entire Eclipse-Android build system stopped working. I have since tried everything i could find on the internet on how to solve this. In vain. Kindly let me know if someone has a DETERMINISTIC way to get this issue fixed.

Here's the error log while i try to build the very basic hello-world project:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product  
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

Error
Sun Nov 06 01:17:32 CST 2011
Failed to load properties file for project 'ddkcdlcds'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your debug keystore? I got the same error in Eclipse when mine expired.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins), if you do not know how.

Comment: yep. tried that. even recreated the debug.keystore and included the avd path in the env PATH var. no use. see my comments below for the other answer. i am kinda giving up at this point. thx a lot for your support though.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but it's worth a shot:

1) backup your entire workspace, than delete it.

2) re-create the workspace, using the same name

3) try the hello-world project, if successful -> re-import all projects from backup.

**Edit:** Checking environmental variables

Control Panel -> System Properties/System -> Advanced settings -> Environment Variables;

Under the "System variable" section, you will look for "Path". 
Double-click on it.
In the "Variable values" section, add at the very end the location of the tools & package-tools folder, with a semicolon separating these two paths from the rest, e.g. 
`%SystemRoot%;C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;C:\android-sdk-windows\tools`.

Comment: did not work @hovanessyan :( i tried a ton of stuff including reinstalling the SDK, ECLIPISE, ADT on eclipse, etc. I even removed the keystore in .android folder. The only thing i have not tried is reinstalling the JDK or JRE. It's really a frustrating issue.

Comment: on a simple hello-world project, the autobuild or project-->build, project-->build-all options did not work. But when i chose the project-->run-as option, the apk was built. But on other "non-trivial" already existing projects that were re-imported into the new workspace, the run-as option fails as well telling me to fix project issues before i can run.

Comment: Have you set any environmental variables?

Comment: I have edited my answer and now it contains info how to check or setup the environmental variables on your system.

Comment: yep. env paths are all ok. i am giving up because the following seems to work. i repeat: if i right click and say - "run as android application", i get my apk. But it does not want to generate it automatically via "Build Automatically" or "Build" option. So, i am a bit frustrated but bearing with this odd behavior. BTW, I use vista.

Answer (score 0):

I close the Eclips and started again the problem solved.