# Android Project error on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My android pojects in eclipse suddenly had errors on root level but cannot be traced... It only show the error icon but no error on the codes. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have any error messages to go with this? Could be that the project cannot find the files - just guessing really though

Comment: You can always look at the problems via **Problems** tab. Open it and you should see what causes the error.

Comment: I looked at the problems tab and the error was "Error generating final archive. Unable to get debug signature key"...

Answer (score 1):

Try refreshing the project (click on the project node and press F5 [Fn + F5 on mac]).
Then press the Project menu (top menu bar) --> Clean --> Select checkbox for your project --> OK.

See if that fixes for you.

Comment: I tried it a lot of times. No luck. I think this is not on a project level error. As I try to launch my other projects [perfectly working ones before], they don't run anymore and has the same error.

Comment: Do you have library projects and did you upgrade the ADT tools recently by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh or clean projects, restart eclipse.If it does'nt work try to restart your computer.If you still got that error create new project and copy all content from old to new.

Answer (score 0):

Check windows --> Preferences --> (on Left side) Android --> reset the SDK location

It might solve your problem.

Comment: No luck. My error on the problems tab "Error generating final archive. Unable to get debug signature key"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting your debug keystore? Sounds like it may have expired.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins).