# Eclipse - Several Errors After Altering Proguard and Manifest Files

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I have an Android project for which I use the Eclipse IDE and I wanted to try an use the ProGuard tool to obfuscate/shrink my code. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work with Eclipse throwing up a ProGuard error when I try to export my project.

To resolve this I altered the necessary project properties file to NOT use ProGuard but Eclipse just complained there were errors with the project which needed to be resolved. I tried cleaning the project, refreshing too but all to no avail. As I use a Mercurial for source control I reverted to my last good sources but now Eclipse throws up even more errors which I cannot get rid of:

> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource is out
> of sync with the file system: '/XXXXX/AndroidManifest.xml'.
>
> loadAndParseRClass: failed to find manifest package for project
> XXXXXXX

I've never been a great fan of Eclipse but how can I clean my project and get it back to a NON proguard state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem. There's ANOTHER error log in Eclipse called 'Problems' which tells me my Debug certificate has expired on 25/12/2011. Handy how Eclipse labels this as a 'problem' and not an error and gives no indocation other that a red x that there's some sort of problem!

Anyway I resolved this by going [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

Comment: Looks like deleting the debug certificate also works to fix the "failed to find manifest package" error even _without_ having the "debug certificate expired" message. Go figure 

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you Refresh your project so that the state of your Workspace/IDE agrees with your state on disk (Right click on the project and select "Refresh"). This will get rid of the first error you have.

And then just do a Team -> Revert on your projects and select the files that you have changed and want to revert to the checked-in version.

Comment: Refresh does nothing and I've reverted to to the files I want already. Errors remain.

Comment: Restart Eclipse? Before restarting, rename the error log file (WORKSPACE/.metadata/.log) so that you get a clean indication of the problems. And if things remain there, can you post them? (Edit your post).

Comment: I renamed .log as log.backup.txt so that I had no .log file. Restarted Eclipse and STILL there's a red error 'x' against the project but now nothing shows at all when I select View->Error log