# error in running android project

Tags: android, eclipse

when i'm trying to run an android project which shows the warning message :

```
 Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.
```

but there's no error showing in the code or other section on the project except the project name. like :

[image]

I've cleaned, refreshed the project but it remains same.

how can i identify and remove the error ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All errors and warnings with detailed description could be found on "Problems" view - usually a tab in the bottom right part of the eclipse window. If it isn't there, use `Window -> Show View -> Problems` to show it.

Comment: it showing the error message according to your instructions .. 
Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 1/5/12 6:27 PM

Answer (score 1):

Let your tooling generate a new certificate by deleting your current certificate, see:

["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Has the project worked before, but suddenly stopped?

Have you changed anything in the res folder? I've found that if you mess up one of your resource files (drawable, layout etc) it can have this effect. Double check to make sure none of your resources have spaces or capital letters in the name. If you have recently added a new drawable, try removing it temporarily to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: yes it worked correctly before adding an activity, i didn't add any resource, but it is not showing any error in the activity calss !!

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project, click Properties and choose Java Build Path. Check the tabs there and see if you see any errors.

Sometimes resources there go missing due to folders being removed / moved causing the problems you're experiencing.