# How to find ~/.android/debug.keystore in Mac OS X for Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, keystore

I am very new to Android development. Now am facing this problem in Java Eclipse,

```
Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 1/11/12 12:52 PM       Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

I searched in google and found the answer for my problem from this link ["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins). They gave the answer for my question. I am using Eclipse in `Mac OS X`. They gave solution that to delete `debug.key` from `Preferences - Android - Build - Default debug keystore` . I found the `~/.android/debug.keystore`from that location and i tried to delete debug.keystore from `Default debug keystore:` but, i can't delete it from that location because it is not editable. Can anyone please solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not to offend the proud users of Eclipse, but have you considered using Intellij IDEA for Android development? From my experience, this IDE is way more reliable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just rename or delete it manually in a terminal with: `rm ~/.android/debug.keystore or mv ~/.android/debug.keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore-backup`
[Or have a look  at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

Answer (score 1):

In android studio terminal write this command:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Comment: running this from my `my-react-native-app/android/` folder placed the `debug.keystore` file in the `my-react-native-app/android/app/` folder, not in my `~/.android` folder