# Android change development environment

Tags: android, eclipse

Currently I am using Eclipse IDE with ADT plugin for my Android application development, but when I change the same source code to another machine with same IDE and ADT Plugin, the generated APK cannot be installed as upgrade, android show a error message (I don't  remember the error message)

Since that error, I use the original IDE to compile an APK and finally upgrade on the installed devices.

What I need to add/change in other machines to avoid install errors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same keystore to build your app when you test.

[Android: keytool error on the command line when locating debug.keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639275/android-keytool-error-on-the-command-line-when-locating-debug-keystore)

or on a Mac:

[How to find ~/.android/debug.keystore in Mac OS X for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893989/how-to-find-android-debug-keystore-in-mac-os-x-for-android)

Copy the debug keystore from one machine to the other. You may want to make a back up if you have multiple projects that you are debugging, but you should probably just migrate to a common key.

Answer (score 0):

The apk generated will have a different key therefore it cannot be installed as an update.

Comment: How to obtain the app key to set in other environment?

Comment: you can copy the debug key and use it on the other IDE to make the APK appear the same to the device/emulator, so this is not a correct answer...