# Deleted debug.keystore file. How do I generate it again?

Tags: android

I had deleted debug.keystore file as I had forgotten the password to access it using keytool. How do I retrieve it or generate it again?

If I create a new keystore file using keytool then the eclipse crashes if I add it in the preferences.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The same mechanism as for an expired debug key should work, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2196397/1127492

Comment: Even though I can regenerate it, I am still not able to do anything to it as I've forgotten the password.

Comment: The password for the debug keystore is "android"

Comment: @NickT Oh man you saved me from wasting the 31st minute on this. Just needed the debug keystore password while generating a SHA256. All my years of experience is a waste now! I did I forgot the default password being `android`!

Answer (score 1):

debug.keystore It is generated automatically - if missing - when you build and run a project from eclipse.

Comment: but i changed my operating system and now im in a mac. i have the same project that imported in eclipse but it seems generates another keystore file

Comment: hi @Fcoder..u found any solution for this???

Comment: @Fcoder, I'm also interested whether you managed to restore  the lost keystore file. Please, let us know